# How to prevent partial crash during VLAN configuration on a HP ProCurve 3500

Tags: hp, vlan, hp-procurve

As you can see from my question, I have a VLAN configuration problem with a ProCurve 3500.
The goal is to remove a VLAN from the existing configuration, however when I use the WEB UI to do this, I cannot modify ports to be assigned to a different VLAN or the Default VLAN. I always get the message "config failed", which is not very helpful.

When I try to do it over telnet, the router somehow partially crashes and the utilization on all ports is at 100% and I can barely use the web ui. After a reboot everything is fine again, but the configuration was not changed. The traffic after this partial crash looks like a broadcast storm, however there are definitely no loops in the segment.

I also updated to the latest stable firmware, but the problem persists.

Comment: Try doing it from the console if you're having issues. This will let you monitor the switch. However, are you *sure* your config changes aren't breaking stuff?

Comment: What firmware version are you on?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, you mean over the serial port? I'll do that as soon as I can find an adapter to somehow connect to it... however I don't htink this configuration change should break anything, since this VLAN is not used and I just wanted to unassign the ports from the existing VLAN. Firmware version is K.15.08.0013

Answer (score 0):

Although this is quite an old issue, it appears to be unsolved. I've come across this thread in search for a solution to this particular problem.

For anyone interested, I've worked it out: You can do it by UI. All you have to do is to manually assign the ports to your Default VLAN (Tagged or Untagged), thus removing their assignment to the VLAN you're going to delete. I also removed the IP configuration from the VLAN settings. This way, I was able to successfully delete the VLAN. HTH.